# ERROR with åäö using Word.Interop: Find Replace c#.Net

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a word document which I pass to a function that super script everything between two "£"'s. The problem is that if I don't have enabled English setting on my computer there will display a error (in swedish) complaining about the matching. I guess it has something to do with this particular line `doc.Find.Text = "£([A-Z]{1,5})£";` since the document also contains letter å,ä and ö. However I can't get it to work no matter what I try, I'm really stuck. I'm not an Interop expert so if anyone could help me out I would appreciate it a lot!

```
public void SuperScript(Word.Range doc)
    {
        doc.Find.Replacement.Font.Superscript = 1;
        doc.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
        doc.Find.Text = "£([0-9]{1,5})£";
        doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";

        doc.Find.Execute(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        doc.Find.Text = "£([A-Z]{1,5})£";
        doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";

        doc.Find.Execute(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        doc.Find.Text = "£([a-z]{1,5})£";
        doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";

        doc.Find.Execute(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing... Hope this is an answer for you...
You could do Something like that `"£(\w[^0-9]{1,5})£"` or `"£(\D{1,5})£` excluding numbers. If you don't care about the type of characters returned, you could just do `"£(.{1,5})£"`